# On input type=radio checked, add a class to input=text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I link a radio button and a text input filled so when the radio is selected the text in the input text area will also change to lets say... red-bold?

I know the logic is:
When radio-A and input-text-A is checked, add CSS class to input-text-A.
When unchecked remove class. If radio-B is selected change input-text-B, and so on...

But right now the simple script targets all text inputs.

```js
$('input[type=text]').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-inline">
  <label class="" for="">
    <input class="" type="radio" name="answer-Q1" value="option1"> A. </label>
  <input type="text" name="answers" class="" placeholder="" required>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-inline">
  <label class="">
    <input class="" type="radio" name="answer-Q2" value="option1"> B. </label>
  <input type="text" name="answers" class="" placeholder="" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Change binding on the radios, evaluate which radio value is selected, adjust the text input accordingly.

Comment: You can provide an attribute to the corresponding input texts to affect only the one text field

Comment: Your provided html snippet is slightly smelly in that you only have a single radio button per name.

Comment: Side note - I wouldn't name the class `red`... you have chosen red for some reason, to indicate something — name the class for the _reason_, the _something_. A class should describe what something _is_ or its _state_, then you decide how things in that state should look (in this case: red). The reason/state won't change, but the style/color you apply to it might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your markup, there's actually no need to add any classes or use javascript, you can do what you want with pure CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + input[type="text"] { 
    color: red; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

As for how to add the class with jQuery, I tend to write "robust" solutions that are maybe a bit longer, but are not as "brittle" (meaning: if markup changes a bit, the script will still work).  The way I would write this - assuming no control over markup - would be using jQuery's [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to locate the target text inputs:

```
// no-conflict-save document ready shorthand
jQuery(function($) {
     // bind to the "change" event of all inputs that are radio buttons
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
        // find the text input
        var $text_input = $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="text"]');
        // if there isn't one, get out
        if ( ! $text_input.length ) {
            return;
        }

        // if the radio button is checked, add the class
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $text_input.addClass('red');
        } else {
            // otherwise, remove the class
            $text_input.removeClass('red');
        }
    });
});
```

However, if I DID have control over markup, I would add a class to the radio input element, and use that to both make the script more "generically" useful, as well as narrow down the scope of which inputs were being bound (which would allow this same script to work effectively on checkboxes + text inputs as well):

```
// no-conflict-save document ready shorthand
jQuery(function($) {
     // bind to the "change" event of any inputs with the "watch-change" class
    jQuery('input.watch-change]').on('change', function() {
        // find the text input.  Note, this would find multiple text inputs if they existed.
        var $text_input = $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="text"]');
        // if there isn't a text input to work with, get out
        if ( ! $text_input.length ) {
            return;
        }

        // if the radio button is checked, add the class
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $text_input.addClass('red');
        } else {
            // otherwise, remove the class
            $text_input.removeClass('red');
        }
    });
});
```

And, honestly, with a better understanding of your project scope, it might be possible to write an even more efficient, re-usable snippet of script.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to accomplish this only with the CSS. I have to clean up my code. At first it wasn't working since each radio was placed in a separate div. (I was doing this in order to use the 'form-inline' class from Bootstrap.)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget) {
        e.currentTarget.next("input[type=text").addClass("red");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $('label:has(input:radio:checked)').addClass('rightAnswer');
    $('label:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').removeClass('rightAnswer');
 
});
```

```css
.container {margin:0 auto; margin-top:50px;}

.rightAnswer {font-weight:bold; color:#2979FF;}

.inputAnswers {width:200px;}

.block {display:block;}

input[type="radio"]:checked + input[type="text"] { 
    color: #2979FF; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <label class="block" for="answer-Q1A">
  <input type="radio"  class=""  name="answer-Q1"  value="1"> A.
    <input type="text" name="answers" class="inputAnswers" id="answer-Q1A" placeholder="" required></label>
   
    <label class="block" for="answer-Q1A">
  <input type="radio" class=""  name="answer-Q1"  value="1"> B.
    <input type="text" name="answers" class="inputAnswers" id="answer-Q1A" placeholder="" required></label>
    
    <label class="block" for="answer-Q1A">
  <input type="radio" class=""  name="answer-Q1"  value="1"> C.
    <input type="text" name="answers" class="inputAnswers" id="answer-Q2A" placeholder="" required></label>
</div>
```